# Difference between C++ editions

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

what is the difference among these languages-

- 1.c++(gcc-4.8.1)
- 2.c++(gcc-4.3.2)
- 3.c++11(gcc-4.8.1)
  Many times while submitting the solutions on coding competitive site i randomly choose any of these and i haven't found any significant difference yet. Please anyone clarify this in detail.

Comment: [C++0x/C++11 support](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Comment: gcc-XXX. Those are not languages but different versions of the compiler. Larger versions usually fix older bugs. C++ (short for C++03 currently) and C++11 are different versions of the same language. Though backward compatibility is a high priority for the language developers. So if you write C++03 it should work fine in C++11 (it may even speed because C++11 has added built in move semantics).

Comment: @Loki Astari then according to you any newer version of gcc is better than any older one and this is not necessary that any thing that work in newer version will also work in older one and opposite of this is true1

Comment: @Dheeraj: Yep. Bigger version usually means better. Also if you learn to use the new C++11 features your code can potentially leaner and more concise which helps the compiler with optimizations leading to speed benifits. Also move semantics will also help. **BUT** these competition sites are designed to test your algorithmic skills and it is more likely that an reduction in complexity will help your code more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GCC 4.3 changes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html)

[GCC 4.8 changes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html)

As for C++11, it's the most recent version of C++, including several additions to the core language and extends the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the changes history at:
 http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html.